# Navigation using GlobalKey not work if MaterialApp has a builder

Tags: flutter

I need to do navigation using GlobalKey. Previously it worked, but after I add `builder` in the `MaterialApp`, now my navigation no longer works.

Here is my example code to reproduce the issue.

```dart
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xffff5e57),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(secondary: Color(0xffff3f34)),
      ),
      routes: {
        '/second_page': (context) => SecondPage(),
      },
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return HomePage();
      },
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Open New Page"),
            onPressed: _openNewPage,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _openNewPage() {
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/second_page');
  }
}
```

How do I fix it? I still need a navigation using `GlobalKey` also with `builder` in the `MaterialApp`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue and keep the navigation working, you should modify the builder to wrap the provided **child widget instead of returning a new HomePage().** Here's the code:

```
 return MaterialApp(
   navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
   home: HomePage(),
   theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Color(0xffff5e57),
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(secondary: Color(0xffff3f34)),
  ),
    routes: {
    '/second_page': (context) => SecondPage(),
  },
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return child!;
  },);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code, I've removed the `builder` property and used the `onGenerateRoute` property to define the `routes`. The `Navigator.of(context)` is used to push the route when the button is pressed in the `HomePage`. This will make your navigation work as expected.

Follow the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xffff5e57),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(secondary: Color(0xffff3f34)),
      ),
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          // Wrap the output of builder with a Navigator widget
          return Navigator(
            key: navigatorKey,
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
              switch (settings.name) {
                case '/':
                  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage());
                case '/second_page':
                  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage());
                default:
                  return null;
              }
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Open New Page'),
            onPressed: () {
              // Use the GlobalKey to navigate
              navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/second_page');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes that would work, but I still need `builder` for some reason.

Comment: I have updated the code this will made your navigation as expected